# Как создать файл на php в localhost

Tags: php, fopen

**Я хочу создать новый файл где будет пару текстов и когда я пишу вот такой код**[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**на обычном хостинге все работает и файл создается а вот когда этот же код пишу на локалхосте то файл не создается.**

**Вот так и на хостинге создалась** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**А вот это на локалхосте** 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а он есть? а какие права на нём выставлены? и на папке

Comment: Оригинальный конечно подход - разрабатывать на хостинге, а тестировать локально))

Comment: Вместо **die**  рекомендую поставить вывод ошибок. на крайняк try/catch  и посмотреть что выдаёт в качестве ошибки

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Всем спасибо за помощь.
Оказывается я там не те права дал папке.